# What is the best way to measure similarity between two histograms

Tags: statistics, correlation

What is the best way to measure the similarity between two histograms? For example, in the following pictures, how can I tell if the distributions are similar enough?

[image]

[image]

I now have 2 lists of values, and I've normalized them to fall between 0 and 1.

I've tried multiple statistical tests including Pearson, Spearman, and Kolmogorov-Smirnov and it looks like Spearman is the best test to use. However, the Spearman is not consistent all the time, it sometimes gives me a high "s" value but the shapes of the distribution are not similar enough. In theory, a higher (positive) "s" means the values are strongly correlated. Am I even on the right track using correlation to measure similarities? Are there any other tests that can be used to do this?

```
corr0.89_1 = [10.7441, 8.9568, 11.0018, 9.29803, 8.92043, 8.78492, 13.5503, 6.74334, 6.14392, 5.75271, 28.851, 26.8173, 6.52642, 6.56071, 5.7169, 7.3095, 6.36379, 5.74984, 7.10243, 5.87364, 11.2827, 2.94984, 2.84836, 22.8551, 24.8372, 10.6571, 9.7891, 11.3021, 5.89328, 10.1372, 24.0525, 3.49401, 2.16394, 11.2825, 11.6859, 7.9918, 13.2742, 11.1194, 2.49575, 16.733, 27.918, 3.27145, 14.3346, 20.4979, 13.0808, 13.6282, 14.1474, 25.0414, 8.06032, 280.803, 22.0135, 18.2725, 12.9601, 7.64593]
```

```
corr0.89_2 = [9.14167, 6.30561, 7.7479, 8.05475, 7.14188, 7.62774, 9.18454, 1.48037, 1.5912, 2.07612, 21.302, 22.7082, 2.67858, 2.25732, 1.74804, 2.04191, 2.03539, 1.78882, 2.57568, 1.6512, 8.62473, 2.99236, 3.13484, 13.014, 16.2016, 9.17172, 7.97379, 9.12539, 4.8298, 8.42477, 16.0582, 2.68252, 1.92429, 5.6744, 4.70516, 5.20169, 11.0945, 9.10398, 2.68375, 13.6299, 17.3429, 3.19181, 9.41762, 12.2805, 9.92005, 11.5985, 11.7269, 17.4832, 6.66996, 60.8647, 13.9616, 14.9909, 10.4712, 6.13891]
```

```
corr1.0_1 = [0.00905783, 0, 0.0075662, 0, 0.00583336, 0, 0.0101741, 0.00617847, 0.00474902, 0, 0.0243326, 0.0300779, 0.0062144, 0.00581433, 0, 0.00712057, 0.00703617, 0, 0, 0, 0.0101258, 0.00844863, 0.014988, 0.0248553, 0, 0.00680134, 0.00762619, 0.00701553, 0.0106525, 0.00425654, 0.0160354, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0110151, 0.00874536, 0, 0.0182528, 0.0291939, 0, 0.0426431, 0.0141304, 0.0139076, 0.0182638, 0.0177141, 0.021119, 0, 12.3977, 0.0121492, 0.016053, 0.0148212, 0.00767271]
```

```
corr1.0_2 = [0.128504, 0.119172, 0.0403692, 0.148327, 0.132162, 0.0366454, 0.139191, 0.0464803, 0.0235099, 0.0333772, 0.0427275, 0.0510047, 0.0278845, 0.0202271, 0.0918039, 0.129276, 0.0266636, 0.0399166, 0.693549, 0.131911, 0.134276, 0, 0, 0.248764, 0.17239, 0.0450586, 0.0932654, 0.0671463, 0.239433, 0.102551, 0.378029, 0.031807, 0.0181028, 0.107356, 0.145449, 0.0735069, 0.788291, 0.496569, 0.0209139, 0.0983066, 0.0530917, 0.0755444, 0.25198, 0.550969, 0.172254, 0.104131, 0.113987, 0.548016, 0.302768, 126.145, 0.886364, 0.107977, 0.4037, 1.23249]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to define unambiguously what you mean by similarity for the problem you are solving, otherwise each of these coefficients will correctly measure similarity as per their own definition. Let us suppose you define similarity as how similar is the shape of one distribution to the other. In this case, if you resize both histograms to the same scale and place one on top of the other, in case of perfect similarity, each will completely overlap the other; if not, one or both will have some un-lapped parts.

For this definition, Spearman's coefficient will not work since it only measure the correlation between the rank order of the class intervals. We can have two distributions in which the rank order of the intervals are identical but the height of the interval in the two distribution are vastly different. In theory, you can have infinitely many distribution whose Spearman's coefficient is 1 but their shapes is all different. On their other hand, if the Pearson coefficient is 1 then their shape will be exactly be the same and there will be no un-lapped parts.

For more rigorous measures, refer to this link: [Similarity measure between multiple distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82076/similarity-measure-between-multiple-distributions)

Comment: Sorry, let me define similarity here. What I meant by "similar" was the shape of the histograms looked similar. In this case, which test would be more appropriate? By the way, if the data didn't come from a normal distribution, wouldn't Pearson be inappropriate?

Comment: @sensationti Normal distribution is not necessary for Person's similarity test. Eg: Consider two perfectly uniform distribution. The shape of their histograms will be a rectangles. Divide the height of each bar with the total number of observations in each histogram. Now calculate the Pearson coefficient. It will be exactly $1$ showing the the two histograms are completely similar in shape, even though the data came from a uniform distribution and not a normal distribution.

Comment: According to what you said if the Pearson correlation value is high, two histograms should overlap each other better. However, sometimes a smaller correlation gives me better overlap than a higher correlation. (i.e. two lists of values have a correlation of 0.89 but the shape of these two histograms look more similar than the shape of the values that have a correlation of 1.0) Why is this the case?

Comment: @sensationti When you say shapes are more similar, how exactly are you the measuring similarly between the shapes. Then we can work backwards and find the reason

Comment: Mainly by visually looking at it. I simply look at the global maximum and minimum and find the contours in local regions. For example, in the pictures that I included in the question's body, I just connect all the tips of each bar using a curve across colors. If the overall shape of that curve where all the tips are connected greatly overlaps, I can say that the two histograms look similar.

Comment: @sensationti Thats exactly where the problem is. You need to trust the math more than the human eye. The human eye is one of the least reliable source of information in the scientific world. Try this: Show me an example of two distributions where you think just by looking at it that a Person coeff. of $0.89$ looks more similar than that of $1.0$

Comment: I've added an example in the question's body. The two pictures on top have a Pearson correlation of 0.89, and the correlation between the bottom two pictures is 1.0. However, to me, the top 2 pictures look more "1.0" -ish than the bottom ones.

Comment: @sensationti I meant please share the raw data that generated these histograms. Picture are not helpful for analysis.

Comment: I've uploaded the data that I used in the body. To calculate Pearson correlation, I just used scipy.stats.pearsonr in Python.